# Angular Material 2 : SideNav does not properly display over any element in other components

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am having an issue with the Angular Material (NG4) SideNav and its attached overlay does not properly display over top any element in other components (My concern atm applies to my Registration Component in particular).  It is like the sidenav does not know about the rest of the DOM?  I am relatively new to front end work so any help would be appreciated.  I am sure it is something stupidly simple.

Here is my example:

Here is my main.component (ts is not important for this component atm):

```
<main>
<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
  <layout-header></layout-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
</main>
```

Here are my Header Component files:

html:

```
<header>
    <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="push">
        <img src="assets/png/xxxxxxxxxxxx_reversed_white_logo_web.png" alt="xxxxxxxxxxxx Logo" class="logo-wrapper"/>
        <md-toolbar-row>
            <mdb-squeezebox id="side-nav-accordion-wrapper" [multiple]="false" aria-multiselectable="false" class="text-right">
                <mdb-item>
                    <mdb-item-head ripple-radius>Solutions &amp; Services</mdb-item-head>
                    <mdb-item-body>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/solutions-overview/" class="waves-effect" ripple-radius>Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/strategic-growth-consulting/">For B2B</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/for-b2c/">For B2C</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/for-professional-services/">For Professional Services</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </mdb-item-body>
                </mdb-item>
                <mdb-item>
                    <mdb-item-head ripple-radius>Talent Solutions</mdb-item-head>
                    <mdb-item-body>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">HRAssistant</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </mdb-item-body>
                </mdb-item>
                <mdb-item>
                    <mdb-item-head ripple-radius>Resources</mdb-item-head>
                    <mdb-item-body>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/sales-insights/">Sales Insights</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/professional-services-insights/">Professional Services Insights</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/case-studies/">Case Studies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/podcasts/">Podcasts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </mdb-item-body>
                </mdb-item>
                <mdb-item>
                    <mdb-item-head ripple-radius>Our Company</mdb-item-head>
                    <mdb-item-body>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/leadership/">Leadership</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/growth-play-board-of-directors/">Board of Directors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/our-customers/">Our Customers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/our-partners/">Our Partners</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/news-and-events/">News &amp; Events</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/business-development-consultant-careers/">Careers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </mdb-item-body>
                </mdb-item>
                <mdb-item>
                    <mdb-item-head ripple-radius>Blogs</mdb-item-head>
                    <mdb-item-body>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://blog.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/">Sales Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://blog.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/practitioner">Professional Services Blog</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </mdb-item-body>
                </mdb-item>
                <a href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/drive-revenue-growth/">Contact Us</a>
            </mdb-squeezebox>
        </md-toolbar-row>

    </md-sidenav>
    <md-toolbar color="primary">
        <button md-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
            <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
        </button>
        <span>{{title}}</span>
    </md-toolbar>
</header>
```

typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'layout-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "GrowthPlay Authentication";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here are my Registration Component files:

html

```
<section id="registrationComponent_old" class="container-fluid" role="document">
<div novalidate class="row">
  <md-card class="card col-sm-6 mx-auto">
      <md-card-header class="col-12 text-center">
          <h2 class="skin-primary white-text col-12 text-center">
              <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>Local Registration
          </h2>
      </md-card-header>
      <div class="card-body">
          <form novalidate [formGroup]="registrationForm">
              <div class="error  col-sm-12"></div>
              <div class="md-form form-sm col-sm-12 row">
                   <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                      <input formControlName="email" id="email" class="form-control text-primary" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <i class="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
                      <input formControlName="password" id="password" class="form-control  text-primary" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <i class="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
                      <input formControlName="confirmPassword"  id="confirmPassword" class="form-control  text-primary" type="password" placeholder=" Confirm Password" name="confirmPassword">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
                      <input formControlName="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control  text-primary" type="text" placeholder="Enter your First Name" name="firstName">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
                      <input formControlName="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control  text-primary" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" name="firstName" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12 row">
                      <div class="col">
                          <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-12 row">
                          <mdb-ng-select class="col-4" [options]="optionsSelect" placeholder="Enter your language" ></mdb-ng-select>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-12 button-row">
                          <button md-raised-button color="accent" id="registerLink" class="col-lg-5 col-md-12" href="#" (click)="register()">Register</button>
                          <a md-raised-button color="primary" id="cancelLink" class="col-lg-5 col-md-12" [routerLink]="['/login']">Cancel</a>
                  </div>

                  <!--</div>-->
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>

      <!--<div>
          <p>{{newUser.firstName}}</p>
          <p>{{newUser.email}}</p>
          <p>{{newUser.returnUrl}}</p>
      </div>-->
  </md-card>


</div>

</section>
```

typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { IUserRegistration, IUser} from "../../../shared/interfaces";
import { UserRegistration, User } from "../../../shared/models";
import { Router, RouterModule, Routes, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { UserResource } from "../../../shared/resources";
import { AuthenticationService } from "../../../shared/services";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration',
  templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration.component.scss']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

private newUser: IUserRegistration = new UserRegistration();
private registrationForm: FormGroup;
private optionsSelect: Array<any>;
private languages: Array<string>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.registrationForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(),
    lastName: new FormControl(),
    email: new FormControl(),
    password: new FormControl(),
    confirmPassword: new FormControl(),
    language: new FormControl()
  });

  this.optionsSelect = [
     { value: 'en-us', label: 'English' }
  ];

  this.languages = ["eng"];

  }

  constructor(private user: UserResource, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private http: Http, private authentication: AuthenticationService) {
}

register() {
  this.newUser = this.user.save(this.newUser, (response) => {
  var returnUrl;
  this.authentication.getAuthorization(this.newUser.returnUrl).subscribe(data => {
    window.location.href = data.url;

  });//this.router.navigateByUrl(data.url));



});

}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is ..'Not displaying properly" can mean a lot of things !!!and please try to create a plunk for the same

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted before I was finished.

Comment: I am not sure how to create a plunker for this (or any plunker for that matter) there are a lot of moving parts.

Comment: The problem it's that your sidenav container doesn't contain your router, and therefore will not work as expected full screen mode. Pop out the container to the top level of your app

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have temporarily moved the <router-outlet></router-outlet> to the header component html, but I get the same results

Comment: If you draw up an expected UI in paint I can write out the code structure you'll want. The general idea is that *anything* you want covered up by the <md-sidenav> must be *inside* the <md-sidenav-container>. If you want it truly full screen you need <md-sidenav-container> to be in your root component.

Comment: Thanks, I had an aha moment and moved the container itself out to the main component's html and the menu now properly displays in front.  But there is no overlay.  I have updated my post to reflect the new code

Comment: @Z.Bagley Your comment was on the nose.  If you could post it as an answer I will mark it as so.  However, it just seems a little wrong the way you have to do this; I am still trying to wrap my head around the concept the used for naming, etc.;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that anything you want overlapped by a sidenav must be inside a `md-sidenav-container`. For your example you'd want it to look something like this:

```
<md-sidenav-container fullscreen>
<main>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav>
    <layout-header></layout-header>
  </md-sidenav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

The reason it works like this is that you're able to leave the header and footer visible for any "permanent" type routing concerns.Here's an example template using @angular/material alongside @angular/flex-layout implementing this method.

```
<div fxFlexFill fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">
    <!-- Top Nav -->
    <div fxFlex="100px">
      <app-top-nav fxFlexFill FxLayout="row"></app-top-nav>
    </div>

    <!-- Body -->
    <div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around stretch">
      <md-sidenav-container fxFlexFill>
        <!-- Side-Nav -->
        <div [ngClass]="{'side-nav-closed': navIsClosed, 'side-nav-open': !navIsClosed }">
          <md-sidenav #sidenav [ngClass]="{'side-nav-closed': navIsClosed, 'side-nav-open': !navIsClosed }" mode="push" align="left" opened="true">
            <app-side-nav fxFlexFill></app-side-nav>
          </md-sidenav>
          <div class="circle clickable" [ngClass]="{'circle-closed': navIsClosed }" (click)="sideNavToggle();"><md-icon>{{ navIcon }}</md-icon></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Main Outlet -->
        <div fxFlex fxFlex.lt-sm="500px" class="overflow">
          <router-outlet fxFlexFill></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </md-sidenav-container>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div fxFlex="50px">
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this way the side nav bar uses `mode="push"` to only push out the one div. You can see a [working demo here](http://demo.datastandards.limited/home) and view the [github source code here](https://github.com/zbagley/ngx-flex-material-template).

Comment: Thank you for the extra explanation as well.  It helps me see the forest as well as the trees, which tends to be the way I learn.  I like seeing the big picture so I can plug in new concepts.  Great answer.